# Store tokens from strtok() in double pointer "2d array"

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, malloc, strtok

Input file:

```
s0 0 3 0 10
s1 0 6 0 20
s2 0 5 0 11
s3 0 6 0 20
s4 67 2 0 25
s5 5 4 0 1
s6 0 2 0 5
s7 0 4 0 28
s8 0 3 0 20
s9 45 5 0 6
s10 103 3 0 2
```

Code:

```
char ** customers;
char *p;
customers = (char **)malloc(50 * sizeof(char *));

for (int i = 0; i < 50; i ++)
{
    customers[i] = (char *)malloc(5 * sizeof(char *));
}

int z = 0;
while ((nread = getline(&line, &len, stream)) != -1)
{
    int i = 0;
    p = strtok (line, " ");

    while (p != NULL)
    {
        customers[z][i] = *p;
        i++;
        p = strtok (NULL, " ");
    }
    z++;

}
printf("%s\n", customers[0]);
```

So essentially, I am reading each line of txt input file, breaking it down into tokens with strtok(), and store them into a double pointer(customers) that functions like a 2d array, but after the while loop exits, I can’t access the each individual token within this “2d array”, I can access the whole line of it with

```
printf(“%s\n”, customers[0])

outputs:
s0301
```

but this only prints the first character of each token rather than the whole string.
How can I access the full tokenised string with for example like this

```
printf(“%s\n”, customers[0][0])
printf(“%s\n”, customers[0][1])
printf(“%s\n”, customers[0][2])
printf(“%s\n”, customers[0][3])
printf(“%s\n”, customers[0][5])

outputs:
s0
0
3
0
10
```

Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: Well at the moment you're only storing the first character. `*p` is the first character of the token, and `customers[z][i]` is a one character storage space.

Comment: If you want an array of customer records, start by defining `srruct customer`. What should one customer record contain?

Comment: @n.m. Coming from a Java and c++ background, used to just using vectors, so I was trying to do the same thing here with C. Switched over using struct has solved my problem, so cheers!

Answer (score 0):

A string is stored as a character array `char*`. Since your array `customers` has the type `char**` and you want to access the string with `customers[z][i]` the type of `customers` must be `char***`. When filling the array from a line string use

```
p = strtok(line, " ");
while (p != NULL)
{
    customers[z][i] = p;
    i++;
    p = strtok (NULL, " ");
}
```

A problem will be the `malloc` since you don't know the exact length of each string.

Comment: Sorry sent by mistake

Comment: tried changing to char *** customers, but printf("%s\n", customers[0][0]); outside of while loop prints nothing

Comment: what happens when you print customers inside the loop?